# button value on form submission via post

Tags: php, html

When I write

```
<form id="" action="" method="post">   
 <ol>
     <li id="">   
       <button type="submit" id="" name="Email" value="b1">
          <span class="account-name"></span>          
          <span class="account-email" id="account-email-0"></span>   
       </button>   
     </li>   
 </ol>
```

Now,when I will click on the first button type=submit will I get b1 value in my post params?

Comment: TIAS - Try It And See. The best way to know if something actually works is to just test it.

Comment: $_POST['Email'] should be "b1"

Comment: echo `$_POST['Email']`;// b1

Comment: Thanks.Shankar-It was just dummy data.Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it yourself. just `print_r` the `$_POST`
Your answer is:
Yes you will get b1 value by the name of Email :

```
[Email] => b1
```